# How to escape "$" in R markdown and slidify it?

Tags: r, rstudio, r-markdown, slidify

When write some notes in R Markdown, I need to escape the dollar sign, making sentence within two dollar sign not a formula.

I have tried `\$ blah blah blah \$` and `\\$ blah blah blah \\$` or even `<p>$ blah blah blah </p>$`.

What works is `$`. But I don't want to highlight it.

ps: I want to slidify it, so both `\$` and `\\$` don't work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You just need to use backslashes `\` to escape, not forward slashes:

```
Line with $\text{Math:} \frac{3}{4}$.

Line with \$ escaped dollar signs \$.
```

Comment: My fault. I mean `\$` and `\\$`, and I slidify it.